# Why doesn't my switch statement match any case?

Tags: javascript, regex

When I use **switch statement** , **none** of the cases matches the 'prefix'.
But if I replace switch statement with **if-else**, everything works. 
Why?

Thank you

```
//UPDATED
//el is DIV element. For example el.id='mph_4';
var prefix = /^[a-z]+/.exec(id);
//------------- SWTICH -------------------------
switch (prefix) {
    case 'mph':
        return 1;
    case 'ph':
        return 2;
    case 'mh':
        return 3;
}
//---------------IF-ELSE------------------------
 if (prefix == 'mph') {
        return 1;
    }
    else if (prefix == 'ph') {
        return 2;
    }
    else if (prefix == 'mh') {
        return 3;
    }
```

Comment: probably the type of variable is causing thisi.e. var is a dynamic type.

Comment: Your description seems to differ from the title of your question. Could you rephrase it to make it clear what part is actually going wrong? More specifically, could you provide the contents of `el.id`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`RegExp.exec()` returns an array. So `prefix` is actually array and not a string. If you are sure that exec returns a single string, you can change your switch statement as:

```
switch (prefix[0]) {
    case 'mph':
        return 1;
    case 'ph':
        return 2;
    case 'mh':
        return 3;
}
```

Comment: **EDIT** Comment I was replying to has been deleted.
That's correct. It returns an array. It's trivial to test this. `document.write(/^[a-z]+/.exec("mph")[0]);` returns "mph", whereas if a string was returned it would return "m".

Comment: @RB deleted the comment before I saw yours. You are indeed correct, my bad!

Answer (score -1):

remember to use switch-case-**break**

Comment: `break` isn't necessary if you're returning from the function.

Comment: That still doesn't explain, why *nothing* matches.

Comment: This should have been a comment, not an answer. And, indeed, a `break` would be a complete waste of code here.